# Forbidden : you are not authorized to access the requested resource

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, authorization

I'm trying to access a link through a webView in android

the link works well on browsers but when I tried to make it in the webView I get this message
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhOvj.png)

The link is: http://noipa.mef.gov.it/group/mypa/home

if there anyone has an idea what should I do please help.

my webView code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inCyS.png)

Comment: Probaly has to do with some sort of authorization header or user agent. Use a network monitor like charles to see how the request looks in the browser and then add the missing headers or user agent

Comment: try switching the user agent to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36`

Comment: @SteelToe this is mobile webView you know it uses chrome by default

Comment: Yes, but it uses a mobile user agent. Try the desktop one

Comment: deskTop works well i need to run on mobile

Comment: Exactly, so use a desktop user agent on your mobile web viee

Comment: how to do that?
can i change default browser of webview?

Comment: your not changing the default browser, ur changing the user agent

Comment: like this, lets say you have a web view variabel called webview, so add code like this `webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36");`

Comment: Were you successfull?

Comment: forbidden too :(

Comment: Can you post your web view code

Comment: edited now can you check?

Comment: I will take a look

Comment: Why are you using a SSl tolerant web view

Comment: Just use `new WebViewClient()` instead

Comment: for pressed the handler in case of failure for ssl error

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: can you test the link on your machine?

Comment: I did, it worked fine

Comment: any hints to make it work on my machine?